# Override Chrome new behavior towards cookies with blank samesite attributes

Tags: azure, google-chrome, cookies, csrf, samesite

So now that Chrome has rolled out its newest safety measures against CSRF attacks with ensuring cookies are set w the "samesite" attribute to either lax, strict or none - is there a way to override this new behavior for specific sites? Particularly sites running on the old Azure servers which are sending me cookies without this attribute set and causing all kinds of browsing frustrations whilst using a webapp hosted there. Any ideas?

I have disabled all 3

1. chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies
2. chrome://flags/#enable-removing-all-third-party-cookies
3. chrome://flags/#cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change`chrome://flags/#enable-removing-all-third-party-cookies`, you can leave this on default. This is just controlling UI currently and does not affect site behaviour.

If you are using a managed version of Chrome, e.g. enterprise enrolled in an organisation that can apply policies, then you can make use of `LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabledForDomainList` to specify a list of (as the name implies) domains to retain the legacy cookie behaviour. See: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3/cookie-legacy-samesite-policies

Aside from that, I don't believe there's a built-in way of excluding specific sites from the new behaviour.